# Why is a leading space stopping a regular expression from matching?

Tags: regex, perl, unicode

I have the regular expression `'(\<link [^\>]+\>)'` that matches fine, but adding a space in front of it and it doesn't: `' (\<link [^\>]+\>)'` (without the `'`).

When I use a regular expression to match a `link` tag it matches perfectly:

```
$ echo '<para>Please see Listing <link href="#lst:11-alg1">2.1</link> with the' \
    | perl -pe 's|(\<link [^\>]+\>)|###|g'
<para>Please see Listing ###2.1</link> with the
```

As you can see the `<link...>` is replaced by `###` -- so the regular expression matched.

**When I add a single space before the regular expression it doesn't match any more**:

```
$ echo '<para>Please see Listing <link href="#lst:11-alg1">2.1</link> with the' \
    | perl -pe 's| (\<link [^\>]+\>)|###|g'
<para>Please see Listing <link href="#lst:11-alg1">2.1</link> with the
```

The result is still the original text, no replacement has taken place -- the regexp did not match.

I thought the problem was greedy matching (but I could not imagine where), and I played around with `+?`-modifiers, and `\s`, but to no effect. And it's also not that the regexp starts with a `' '`: when I add `Listing` to the pattern it doesn't match either:

```
$ echo '<para>Please see Listing <link href="#lst:11-alg1">2.1</link> with the' \
    | perl -pe 's|Listing (\<link [^\>]+\>)|###|g'
<para>Please see Listing <link href="#lst:11-alg1">2.1</link> with the
```

I even tried the same with Python: Same result, so it must be something wrong with my regexp.

Comment: @fugu totally, yes. Besides, I tried `\s` as well.

Comment: That's not your everyday run-of-the-mill space, it's a "figure space" ([Unicode U+2007](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2007/index.htm)).

Comment: I am emberassed. It is not a simple space, it is a 3 byte UTF-8 sequence `\xe2\x80\x87` that did not match Perls `\s`: `U+2007 FIGURE SPACE character (&#x2007;)
`

Comment: It's a space, Jim, but not as we know it...

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot you have been quicker then me. Amazing it survived copy-paste into the web.

Comment: @towi if the string is decoded and your perl is not ancient, `\s` will match that character. But if you're not decoding your input, then it won't match :)

Comment: @hobbs `v5.18.2`... but to be on the safe side I will find a safer solution.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: I'm seeing just a regular 0x20. What browser are you using?

Comment: @Borodin Firefox v31.0.

Comment: @hobbs: You're right, but I'm surprised that it matches this space but not a no-break space `"\x{A0}"`

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: Same here. How odd.

Comment: @Borodin U+00A0 falls under legacy semantics because it's under U+00FF. `/\s/u` matches it always in 5.14+. `\s` without `/u` matches it *unpredictably*; setting the utf8 flag on the string, or mentioning certain things in the pattern, will cause it to match.

Comment: @Borodin `/u` enables proper unicode semantics where U+00A0 is matched by `\s` because it has the `Space` property :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you copy your string into Notepad++ that is a special character after Listing ANSI(â€‡). So space would not match it.

Comment: Let's call things what they are: the 'special character' is the [UTF8 sequence for U+2007](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2007/index.htm).